# PHP Associative Arrays - how to match up values based on a condition

Tags: php

I'm passing a team name through a cookie from another page. When the user reaches the new page I check to see if that team name exists in my array if it does then do something, and if it doesn't then do something else. This works fine. However, if the condition is true I want to set the variable $team_color to the color from the nested array where the team name was found.

I can't figure out how to access this.

I'm currently trying to access array_values but with no luck. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Here is what i have so far -

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['TEAM']))

{

$team_cookie = $_COOKIE['TEAM'];

$team_info=Array (

    '0' => Array (

            'team_name' => 'team1',
            'team_color' => 'red'
        ),

    '1' => Array (

            'team_name' => 'team2',
            'team_color' => 'blue'
        ),

    '2' => Array (

            'team_name' => 'team3',
            'team_color' => 'green'
        ),

    '3' => Array (

            'team_name' => 'team4',
            'team_color' => 'yellow'
    )
);

if(in_array($team_cookie, array_column($team_info, 'team_name'))) { 


   $team_color = array_values($team_info, 'team_color');


    // Do something        

}

}
```

Comment: You don't just need to know if the value is in the array, you also need to know the associated index. Use [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-search.php) instead of `in_array()`.

Comment: I posted the answer please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to get the team color for a team name, you should restructure your `$team_info` array for a faster access with keys being team names and values being team color. We first retrieve all `team names` using `array_column` and then same for `team_color`. We later use `array_combine()` to make the first array values as keys and second array values as values of those keys. Something like below-

```
<?php

$team_info = array_combine(array_column($team_info,'team_name'),array_column($team_info,'team_color'));
```

The above code restructures it from :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [team_name] => team1
            [team_color] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [team_name] => team2
            [team_color] => blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [team_name] => team3
            [team_color] => green
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [team_name] => team4
            [team_color] => yellow
        )

)
```

TO

```
Array
(
    [team1] => red
    [team2] => blue
    [team3] => green
    [team4] => yellow
)
```

Now, you could just do `echo $team_info[$team_cookie]` to get the team color.

**UPDATE:**

If your requirement, is to just search for a single team's color , then you could just use a simple foreach loop and check if the `team_cookie` matches any team name, then assign it's `team_color` to a variable.

```
<?php
$team_color = "";
foreach($team_info as $each_team){
    if($each_team['team_name'] === $team_cookie){
        $team_color = $each_team['team_color'];
        break;
    }
}


echo $team_color;
```

However, if there are multiple team names to search for, then do as above by restructuring the array. You could also keep them in sessions for better performance time wise.

Comment: There is no need to transform the whole array when only one element is of interest.

Comment: @Blackhole Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['TEAM'])) {
    $team_cookie = $_COOKIE['TEAM'];
    $team_info=Array (

        '0' => Array (

                'team_name' => 'team1',
                'team_color' => 'red'
            ),

        '1' => Array (

                'team_name' => 'team2',
                'team_color' => 'blue'
            ),

        '2' => Array (

                'team_name' => 'team3',
                'team_color' => 'green'
            ),

        '3' => Array (

                'team_name' => 'team4',
                'team_color' => 'yellow'
        )
    );
    $color = ""; 
    foreach ($team_info as $team_info) {
       if($team_cookie == $team_info['team_name'] ) {
        // Do something  
        $color = $team_info['team_color'];
        break;
       }
    }
    echo $color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code this will help you.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['TEAM'])){
    $team_cookie = $_COOKIE['TEAM'];
    $team_info=array (
        '0' => array (
                'team_name' => 'team1',
                'team_color' => 'red'
            ),
        '1' => array (

                'team_name' => 'team2',
                'team_color' => 'blue'
            ),
        '2' => array (

                'team_name' => 'team3',
                'team_color' => 'green'
            ),
        '3' => array(

                'team_name' => 'team4',
                'team_color' => 'yellow'
        )
    );
    $find = check_inarray($team_cookie,$team_info);
    if($find>0){
        //If found do some action
    }


    function check_inarray($team_cookie,$team_info){
        for($i=0;$i<count($team_info);$i++){
            if($team_info[$i]['team_name']==$team_cookie)        
                return true; 
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```